# padding canvas affecting border

Tags: css, image, border, padding, spaces

i created canvas.
in the css file i used border property :

```
#cnvs {

    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
     border-radius:100px;
      border-style: solid;
    border-color: #ffffff;
    padding: 50px;
```

Now, the problem is when i add padding.
Look what id does- 
[Demo](http://s27.postimg.org/r3th39yv7/Screen_Shot_2014_06_29_at_14_26_18.png)

i want to "padding" the image with the border.. so there will be no spaces between them..is it possibe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the padding to the parent div. 
Or turn padding into margin.

```
#cnvs { 
    margin: 50px;
}
```